# C# Lambda : using Event<T>()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an ArrayList of FrameworkElements in variable "selectedElementArray"

and the below code is used to align controls to top

```
    double top = 100;
    selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(fe => Canvas.SetTop(fe, top));
```

this is working fine.

but i need to avoid a FrameworkElement, say parentElement, which exists in "selectedElementArray"

```
selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
       .ToList()
       .Except(parentElement)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(fe => Canvas.SetTop(fe, top));
```

i tried using "Except". but throwing some exception.

pls help....

Binil

Comment: what kind of exception? are you sure parentElement in the selectedElement array?

Comment: *What* exception?  The exception will give you help.  The `Except` method expects an `IEnumerable<object>`, not a single `object` - that would give you a compile time error.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, yes parentElemtn is int selecteElementArray

Comment: @Kirk, the Exception is The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: binil: That's a compiler error, not an exception. Exceptions only happen when your code is actually running.

Comment: @binil Then you are getting the compile time error that I described above. You can't use `Except` in that way because it expects an `IEnumerable` as a parameter.  Use a `Where` like the answers below suggest.

Comment: And why are you using `ArrayList` and `Cast<FrameworkElement>` instead of `List<FrameworkElement>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a `where` clause.

```
selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
   .Where(element => element != parentElement)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(fe => Canvas.SetTop(fe, top));
```

To use `except`, you need to pass an `IEnumerable`:

```
selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
   .Except(new FrameworkElement[]{ parentElement })
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(fe => Canvas.SetTop(fe, top));
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
       .Where(fe => fe != parentElement)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(fe => Canvas.SetTop(fe, top));
```

Or maybe:

```
foreach (var fe in selectedElementArray.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                                       .Where(fe => fe != parentElement))
    Canvas.SetTop(fe, top);
```